# Duration of data in a Global Temporary table?

Tags: sql, oracle

Can someone please tell me: how long will data be there in a Global Temporary table?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

They can be SESSION based (data survives a commit but not a disconnect/reconnect).  They can also be TRANSACTION based (data disappears after a commit).

This creates a transaction based temp table:

```
create global temporary table temp_table_transaction on commit delete rows ...
```

This creates a session based temp table:

```
create global temporary table temp_table_transaction on commit preserve rows ...
```

Answer (score 15):

When you create a [temporary table](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm#sthref7482) you have [two options](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_7002.htm#i2189569) for data persistence:

- `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS` (default) and
- `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`

If you don't specify a persistence clause, or specify `ON COMMIT DELETE ROWS`, the data in the table will be transaction-specific (it will be deleted upon commit or rollback).

If you specify `ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS`, the data will stay until the end of your session.

Comment: **ON COMMIT** only works on **DECLARE** GLOBAL TEMPORAY TABLE

Comment: @Stavr00 Well `DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE` is not a valid command so I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to say here.

Comment: I still dont understand what me means either.

Comment: I suspect @Stavr00 meant to emphasize that you have to choose one or the other mode when you create the table (i.e., in the DDL, which is where "declare" comes in) and you don't get to go back and forth to choose delete or preserve later on in your actual insert/merge statements. Though you did say "when you create" so maybe they misread the answer.

Answer (score 5):

If the table was created with "on commit preserve rows" then data will remain until the end of the current session.  If it was created with "on commit delete rows" then it will remain until the next commit or rollback.